# Is there an idiomatic way to test nested state branches?

Tags: javascript, redux

So let's say that I have a reducer which has several branches, but each branch is similar enough to generate with a factory function.  So, I create one:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const createReducerScope = scopeName => {
  const scope = scopeName.toUpperCase()

  const contents = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case `${scope}_INSERT`:
        return { ...state, [action.id]: action.item }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  const meta = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case `${scope}_REQUEST`:
        return { ...state, requesting: true }
      case `${scope}_REQUEST_FAILURE`:
        return {
          ...state,
          requesting: false,
          errorMessage: String(action.error)
        }
      case `${scope}_REQUEST_SUCCESS`:
        return {
          ...state,
          requesting: false,
          errorMessage: null
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  return combineReducers({ contents, meta })
}
```

Which I use to compose a larger root-level state tree:

```
const products = createReducerScope('products')
const orders = createReducerScope('orders')
const trades = createReducerScope('trades')

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ products, orders, trades })
```

That should give me a state graph which would look like this:

```
{
  products: { contents, meta },
  orders: { contents, meta },
  trades: { contents, meta }
}
```

If I wanted to test this state, my first instinct is to create a version of this scope in my test suite, and then test that isolated reducer (just asserting against the `contents`, and `meta` branches).

The complication here is that I'm trying to *also* test selectors, and all of the selector designs I've read seem to suggest these two things:

1. You encapsulate your state by colocating selectors and reducers in the same file.
2. `mapStateToProps` should only need to know two things, the global state and a relevant selector.

So here's my problem:  Pairing together these more or less composed reducers with root-level-concerned selectors has made my tests a little thick with boilerplate.

Not to mention that hard-writing selectors with knowledge of the entire tree feels like it defies the point of the reducer modularity attempt.

I'm 100% sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't really find any example code which demonstrates a way to test modular reducers and selectors.

If a selector generally should know the *entire global state*, but you have reducers which are highly composed, is there a clean, idiomatic approach to testing that?  Or maybe a more composable selector design?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The point of colocating selectors and reducers is **reducers and selectors in one file should operate on the same state shape**. If you split reducers into multiple files to compose them, you should do the same for your selectors.

You can see an example of this in my [new Egghead series](https://egghead.io/series/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) (videos [10](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers?course=building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) and [20](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-refactoring-the-reducers) might be especially useful).

So your code should be more like

```
const createList = (type) => {
  const contents = ...
  const meta = ...
  return combineReducers({ contents, meta })
}

// Use default export for your reducer
// or for a reducer factory function.
export default createList

// Export associated selectors
// as named exports.
export const getIsRequesting = (state) => ...
export const getErrorMessage = (state) => ...
```

Then, your `index.js` might look like

```
import createList, * as fromList from './createList'

const products = createList('products')
const orders = createList('orders')
const trades = createList('trades')

export default combineReducers({ products, orders, trades })

export const getIsFetching = (state, type) =>
  fromList.getIsFetching(state[type])

export const getErrorMessage = (state, type) =>
  fromList.getErrorMessage(state[type])
```

This way the root selectors delegate to the child selectors, just like the root reducers delegate to the child reducers. In every file, `state` inside selectors corresponds to the `state` of the exported reducer, and state shape implementation details don’t leak to another files.

Finally, for testing those reducer/selector bundles you could do something like

```
import createList, * as fromList from './createList')

describe('createList', () => {
  it('is not requesting initially', () => {
    const list = createList('foo')
    const state = [{}].reduce(list)
    expect(
      fromList.isRequesting(state)
    ).toBe(false)
  })

  it('is requesting after *_REQUEST', () => {
    const list = createList('foo')
    const state = [{}, { type: 'foo_REQUEST' }].reduce(list)
    expect(
      fromList.isRequesting(state)
    ).toBe(true)
  })
})
```